# How to wait keyboard input without OverflowError

Tags: python, keyboard, wait

I'm using this function to wait user input (y for yes, n for no). It's convenient because it doesn't need to press enter and I can use it with GUI (without writing in console).

```
import keyboard

def WaitingForYOrN():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("y"):
            return True
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("n"):
            return False
```

But when I compile it in an exe file with PyInstaller, this error occur : 
Exception in thread Thread-1:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "threading.py", line 916, in
>   _bootstrap_inner   File "threading.py", line 864, in run   File "lib\site-packages\keyboard__init__.py", line 292, in listen   File
>   "lib\site-packages\keyboard_winkeyboard.py", line 560, in listen
>   File "lib\site-packages\keyboard_winkeyboard.py", line 553, in
>   prepare_intercept ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: : int too long to convert

Does someone have an idea to make it running ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here. The first of which is actually quite simply, all you have to do is force pyInstaller to use 32-bit Python as opposed to the 64-bit version it is presumably using. The second is a bit more complicated and involves modifying the source code of the keyboard import. Go to keyboard_winkeyboard.py line 555 and replace
`keyboard_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboard_callback, GetModuleHandleW(None), None)`
with `keyboard_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboard_callback, ctypes.c_ulonglong(GetModuleHandleW(None)), None)`

Comment: I have tried the second option but error is the same. Do you know the command to compile in 32-bit with PyInstaller ?

Comment: @Izaya Yes, you simply have to change the version of Python you used to build it. Currently you are likely using 64-bit Python, download a 32-bit version and use that to build pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it within my program. It worked fine and had no issues with pyinstaller.

```
print('Would you like to check somewhere else?')

print('[1] Yes')
print('[2] No')

variable1=int(input('Please enter choice: '))

if variable1 == 1:
    do this
elif variable1 == 0:
    do something else
```

Comment: Yes it works but it's not really what i wish. For the moment I create a messagebox yes/no with tkinter.

Comment: You could create two buttons, one being yes and one being no. Once you get the rest of your GUI figured out, you can come back to this and try to resolve the issue. You may decide that you don't need the yes/no option at all in the end.